# Programming STM32 via USB using the CubeProgrammer

Tags: stm32, flash

I have designed my own Board with an STM32F103 Chip. Now i want to add the feature that u can program the STM32 using USB connection. I watched the video https://youtu.be/VlCYI2U-qyM by Phil's Lab. I try to connect the Device with an USB, if this is done, in Device Manager (on Windows 11) the Device is Connected (the Power LED is lighting up) and listed as an Unknown Device.

When trying connecting the Board via the 'Connect' button in the CubeProgrammer, nothing happens and the following error message occurs.

[image]

*Image as Text:*

10:48:33 : *UR connection mode is defined with the HWrst reset mode*
10:48:33 : *Error: Establishing connection with device failed*

What I tried:
I set the **BOOT0 Pin, High,** like Phil's Lab says in his video. And then reconnected the board to the power. I also tried multiple ways of connecting. But nothing really worked.

Comment: This may be relevant. 
https://github.com/bigtreetech/EBB/issues/32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not work, because the STM32F103 factory bootloader does not support USB DFU.

If you want to have USB DFU, you must first program a custom bootloader which enables you with DFU.

Comment: I tried multiple videos on Youtube, can you give me a more specific describtion? In the Datasheet I see it is not possible for the STM32. 

Is there actually a way to use the Bootloader from Github?

Comment: I don't have any better description and I don't know which bootloader from Github you mean. If you want to have a bootloader that can work over USB, you need to find one that suits your design and purposes, whether a DFU or some other kind of USB bootloader. I can't decide that for you.